# What should our policy be on "somewhat" broad questions?

Tags: discussion, policy

Quite a few questions have made it into the close vote review queue already, under the reason "Too broad", including:

- [How do I evaluate the features and performance of radios?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/62/how-do-i-evaluate-the-features-and-performance-of-radios)
- [Are there well-known methods that can help improve my CW copying speed?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-are-some-techniques-for-improving-my-cw-copying-speed)
- [How can I protect equipment against a lightning strike?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-can-i-protect-equipment-against-a-lightning-strike)

What should our policy be regarding these types of questions? I personally believe the latter two should be fine, providing answerers  create comprehensive and well documented answers.

For example saying:

> Just keep practicing, your copy speed will improve eventually

Is neither comprehensive *nor* helpful, however an answer going over several theories or known methods would indeed be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How about list questions?](http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-about-list-questions) - while your phrasing is more about broadness, I think the central issue being dealt with is the same.

Comment: The first one (performance of radios) is worded too broadly. The description is really "are the cheap Chinese HTs OK?" But there is a fine answer to the broader question, basically read chapter 12 of the ARRL handbook (receivers) and chapter 13 (transmitters) and talk to other operators about usability.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked discussion - there's a bit of a difference from list, and just very open-ended. I think it might be worth talking about them in both contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is about the features that make a device suitable for the hobby. There is a very finite list of such qualities. I don't think the question is too broad.

The title of the CW question if a bit broad but the question is good and answerable. Basically it can be answered by referring to Koch and Farnsworth methods.

Lightning strike protection question is important enough to keep and will anyways be repeatedly asked if there are no good answers :)

I hope we are smart enough to evaluate if a question is good based on the issue itself and not just wording of the title or such.

Comment: I updated the title [here](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/32/are-there-well-known-methods-that-can-help-improve-my-cw-copying-speed) Better?

Comment: @dcaswell Yes I think so